# Open Application Automatically

Tags: windows

I need an application to start automatically, when I log in every time. Say for example Microsoft Word should be open automatically When I start my system. What I have to do for this?

Comment: Put a shortcut to the program in your Startup folder. But this is not a programming question.

Comment: It could be: just re-phrase a few things so he's asking about how to build his deployment project.  Is that what you have trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

There are two main ways to do this.

One is by adding a link to your Start Menu under `Programs -> Startup`

The other involves a little bit of registry editing:  Add a reference to the application in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

---

You may use this .reg file as a convenient way to make changes to your registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"uTorrent"="\"c:\\Users\\otac0n\\Downloads\\utorrent.exe\""
```

Just paste that in a file (named "uTorrent.reg" for example), and double click it to import.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click the Start menu, click 'Explore'.
2. Open 'Programs', then open the 'Startup' folder.
3. Click 'File' -> 'New' -> 'Shortcut'.
4. Click 'Browse..' and find the location of the Word EXE file. This will be somewhere like C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 12\WINWORD.EXE.
5. Click 'OK', then 'Next'.
6. Give your shortcut a name (e.g. "Word").
7. Click Finish and you're done.